# Geoprocessing with WCS layers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wcs, geoprocessing-framework

Beginner here with ArcMap and I'm having trouble using geoprocessing tools with WCS layers I uploaded.

Is this an issue of "can't technically use these tools on WCS layers"?

Should I reformat them into another workable format?

Comment: My initial take is "no" they wont work. But I don' know for sure. Are you using Pro or ArcMap? Additionally, can you actually push the service into the tool input parameter?

Comment: ArcMap - it won't let me load it into the input parameter, no.

Comment: Hmmm. Per: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-a-wcs-service-to-arcmap.htm -- If you add the WCS into your map that way, and then use the **layer** as input to the GP tool, it may work. Layer meaning after you add the WCS service to your map, drag the layer name from the Table of Contents into the tool parameter. (or use the drop down to select it). Do NOT try to use the URL or the service connection item into the tool.

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: I've been trying to use both the Merge and Intersect tools. Adding the layer by dragging it into the input doesn't seem to work either.